# Is this Java typing hierarchy correct?

Tags: java, object, wildcard, subtyping

Given the types `List<?>`, `List<Object>`, `List<? super Number>`, `List<Number>`, `List<Integer>`, and `List<? extends Number>`, I am trying to understand their hierarchy.

I know that `List<Integer>` is NOT a subtype of `List<Number>`, even though `Integer` is indeed a subtype of `Number`, so I thought that it was instead a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`.

But `List<? extends Number>` intuitively seems to be a subtype of `List<Number>`, which makes `List<Integer>` a descendant of `List<Number>` after all, as my idea of it shows:

[image]

So, if a type is descended from another, but not directly, is it still a subtype of its ancestor (or I am just wrong in the diagram)? This exercise has also gotten me a bit confused about `?` vs. `Object`...actually, it looks like I might have `List<Object>` and `List<? super Number>` mixed up. I guess one of the biggest questions is, "Is 'everything' an `Object`...or is everything a `?` ?" Or both...or neither?

Comment: Most of your diagram is incorrect, unless `List<U> -> List<V>` means `V is a subtype of U`. For example `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>` - see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason why `List<Integer>` is not a sub type of `List<Number>`.

lets just consider a scenario where a `List<Number>` accepts `List<Integer>`(which would practically wouldn't work).

```
  List<Integer> listI =new ArrayList<Integer>();
  List<Double>  listD = new ArrayList<Double>();
  method(listI);
  method(listD);
```

and you have a method which takes `List<Number>` as an argument.

```
   public void method(List<Number> list) {
    list.add(new Double()); // would fail if you pass an List<Integer> as Integer is not a super type of Integer.
    list.add(new Integer()); //would fail if you pass an List<Double> as Double is not a subtype of Integer       
    }
```

so if your method argument declared as `List<number>` accepts `List<Double>` and you try to add an **Integer** into the **list of Double**.which is wrong, because **Double** is **not a super type** of **Integer** thus `List<Number>` is not a sub type `List<Integer>`.

now consider the same scenario where `List<? extends Number>` is a method argument instead of `List<Number>`

```
            public void method(List<? extends Number> list) {
                      // list.add(new Double()); 
                      // list.add(new Integer());       
               }
```

and now you pass an `List<Integer>` to this method. if it accepts it and you try to add a `Double` to **list of Integers**. **BOOM**... you just added a **Double** to **List of Integer** .

To give an **informal example** . consider an **Animal** supertype with **Cat** and **Dog** as subtypes. 
now, you have a method which accepts `<? extends Animal>` and you pass an **Dog** to this method. and in the method you try to add an **Cat**. its adding a wrong type (a CAT) to your **Dog**, thus  `**List<Dog>**` is not a subtype of  `List<? extends Animal>`

please let me know if this is not expressive enough.Thanks :)

Comment: So the thing to watch out for is anything that allows an argument to come in that may not be compatible with another that comes in?

Comment: no, the argument will be compatible, if its not you'd get a compile time error, you should watch out for cases like adding an Cat into an dog list which was passed as an parameter. here your argument would accept either dog or cat , as they both extend animal, but you should be careful about adding wrong things inside the method.